# All com.android.support libraries must use the same version appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

There were a lot of topics like this but none of them helped me. I have an error as in topic and marked line:`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Everything in project is set automatically and I haven't changed anything yet. My gradle app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mprzenzakdev.wallex"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Test case , How about adding: `implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't clear. You most likely need to add each dependency by itself like below:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

This is an app I have and using the dependencies: [example](https://github.com/julesbond007/android-jigsaw-puzzle/blob/738f5baa417ec5bed7157c4760f6862529ee2c85/app/build.gradle#L55/)

Comment: So I simply copy pasted these four implementations and now line with cardview is underlined and the same error

Comment: If you mouse over that error (assuming you're using Android Studio) if it mentions another library, then add it also...keep doing that until all the dependencies are resolved.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/RYZFnqFZ7Rt5Bfxa8 Unfortunately it doesn't mension (it's intellij but in Android Studio error is the same and it also is unresolvable)

Comment: You need to add this library as well: implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0.'